# When should we use address (&a) while writing a three address code?

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

For this code:

```c
prod = 0 ;
i = 1 ;
do {
    prod = prod + a[ i ] x b[ i ] ;
    i = i + 1 ;
} while (i <= 10);`
```

The generated three address code is

```c
prod = 0
i = 1
T1 = 4 x i // (I am not able to figure out what's happening here)
T2 = a[T1]
T3 = 4 x i // (and here)
T4 = b[T3]
T5 = T2 x T4
T6 = T5 + prod
prod = T6
T7 = i + 1
i = T7
if (i <= 10) goto (3)
```

Why can't we use:

```c
t1 = a[i]
t2 = b[i]
t3 = t1 * t2
```

Comment: Are you asking why the 4 times multiple? Isn’t that because the array elements are 4 bytes wide?

Comment: Why did we use address there?

Comment: Use triple backticks to make a code-formatting block, so you can take out thedouble-spacing and make this readable.